# RenderText/ JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, extjs

I have a DeleteUser function that gets called when user clicks on the delete row icon in an actioncolum.
Here is the code for the function:

```
function DeleteUser(id) { 
Ext.Ajax.request ({
url: 'user/delete/castle',
params: {id: id},
success: function (result,request){
Ext.MessageBox.alert('Success', result.responseText);
},
failure: function (result, request){
alert(result.responseText);
}
});
}
```

Right now, when a user is deleted, a pop-up appears with the title "Success" but the result.responseText parameter is empty.
I need the result.responseText parameter to be "User deleted successfully" but I need to pass that by using RenderText in the delete function that gets called via the url.
Here is the code for the delete function that gets called via the url 'user/delete/castle':

```
public void Delete (int id){
CancelView();
CancelLayout();
User user = User.FindUser(id);
user.Delete();
RenderText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(???));
}
```

Does anyone have any tips as to how to do this? I am new to Ajax requests and JSON.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return a JSON object like

```
{ success = true, message = 'Your message'}
```

to client. 
Here is the way to do it:

**Server code:**

```
var obj = new {success = true, message = "Your success message"}
RenderText(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

To notify a failure you can set `success = false` in above code.

**Client code:**

```
function DeleteUser(id) { 
Ext.Ajax.request ({
url: 'user/delete/castle',
params: {id: id},
success: function (response) {
                var resp = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                alert(resp.message); 
                if (success == false)
                {
                   // perform any specific error handling task
                }                    
            },
failure: function (result, request){
     // Usually this function is called on communication failures. Not called if success = false
     alert(result.responseText);

}
});
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Included information on handling success = false scenario. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! It worked! However, I don't really understand what is happening in the code. How come obj is linked to resp? What exactly is happening here? Also, if success = false, I also want a message to appear saying: " Error! User not deleted!". Would I have to make an if-else statement within the code line var obj = new {success = true, message = "Your success message"} ? I tried doing that but it gives me an error. Thanks again! –